# jsoup for unstructured html page with table

Tags: java, android, html, image, jsoup

i'm trying to get the main img from this [url](http://www.tanja7.com/news-8811/), 
here what i tried so far :

```
Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Element table = doc.select("center").get(1);
    Elements rows = table.select("table[width=970]");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
        Element row = rows.get(1);
        Elements cols = row.select("table[width=634]");
        for (int j = 0; j < cols.size(); j++) {
            Element row1 = rows.get(1);
            Elements cols1 = row1.select("table[width=600]");
            for (int k = 0; k < cols1.size(); k++){
                Element row0 = rows.first();
                Elements cols0 = row0.select("td");
                for (Element image : cols0) {
                    String image2 = image.absUrl("src").toString();
                    Log.i("tanja7 ", "pic  " + image2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the unstructured html page (i don't know how to copy the html code)
[image]
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output/error? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: doc = Jsoup.parse(responseString);

Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

Comment: @luksch i dont have stack trace.. the error there is no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are expecting the inner elements as result of a JSoup select method call. That is not right - you get the elements that match the selector within the "search scope", which is given by the Element(s)/document class instance from which you call `select`. So, if you want to get all table elements of the document you do `doc.select("table")`. This gives you not the rows, but the tables. Maybe you did understand this before, but your variable naming suggests otherwise.

Anyway, here is a selector that works. It will get all img elements that are (not necessarily direct) children of a table that has the attribute `width=600` and is within another table of the document.

```
Elements imgEls = doc.select("table table[width=600] img");
System.out.println(imgEls.first().absUrl("src"));
```

You say the  html is not structured, so you might want to check if the relevant images are really always inside two tables as specified.

**update:**
if you are using a mobile device make sure to add:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

Comment: i got NullPointerException in `System.out.println(imgEls.first().absUrl("src"));`

Comment: `imgEls ` is empty for me

Comment: its ok now.. i had to add ` doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();`  which is specific for mobile device